# SXA Date Range Filter

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.7 and when using Date Range Filter and choose start date equal to end date it doesn't return data.

when i investigated this issue i found that it occurs when the field used is of type date time but it is working with date field.

For example: if i have item with field date time = 2018-08-07T06:30:00Z it doesn't return data when filter by start = 2018-08-07 and end = 2018-08-07

Any Help?

Comment: Edit the raw values of that field (in Content Editor) and check what is the date there. I'm 100% sure that raw values will show you different date that Sitecore field:)